# Xcode 6.3 --> 8.2 simulator crash

Tags: ios, simulator, watchkit, xcode6.3, watchapp

I can't launch my watch app using iOS 8.2 simulator with Xcode 6.3 . I receive this crash at startup :
"Dyld Error Message:
  app was built for iOS 8.3 which is newer than this simulator 8.2"

My iOS app's deployment target is iOS 7.0, my watchKit Extension's, and Watch App's deployment target is 8.2 .

Do you have any idea how can this issue be solved?

Comment: Fot that you just rest the Simulator from `IOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings`

Comment: Try to clean the project. Project > Clean

Comment: Cleaning the project worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Something in your project has a deployment target of 8.3 set.  I suggest you grep through your project and xcconfigs for IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to see where it may be coming from.

Comment: I already checked it multiple times, but I don't have 8.3 set anywhere. I am starting to think that maybe this is a bug on Apple's side... (I already created a bug report for them, and they asked for more details.)

Comment: Show the link line from your build log and the output of 'otool -l /path/to/the/executable | grep -A3 MIN

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy ! Hm... It seems like something is targeting 8.3... Here is the output : 
    `otool -l appname.app/appname | grep -A3 MIN
          cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
      cmdsize 16
      version 7.0
          sdk 8.3`

Comment: Yes, and if you look at your build log you'll probably see that "8.3" is in the command line when linking as well.